# India do or does?

Tags: british-english, indian-english

In pics: India celebrates Rakhi with fervour

Or In pics: India celebrate Rakhi with fervour

which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

In these sentences, India is an example of [synechdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche), where a word (India) is used to represent something with a greater scope (all of the people in India).

Although it represents a group of people, the word India is a singular noun, and so the verb must take the appropriate form for a singular noun. The correct version is therefore:

> India celebrates Rakhi with fervour